# im facing some problem with npm install what am i supposed to do?

Tags: powershell, npm, npm-install

im working on a mini project so i had to open  "npm install" im not able to do that in vs code and in windows power shell ,this is what im getting in the terminal what am i supposed to do

```
PS C:\Users\Owner> node -v
v21.6.0
PS C:\Users\Owner> npm install
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Owner/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Owner\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-01-17T13_25_23_614Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\Users\Owner>
```

Comment: `cd`, probably - do _you_ think there's a `package.json` in `C:\Users\Owner`? https://blog.jonrshar.pe/wtf-npm/errors/enoent

Comment: yes i do have package .json but idk if it is in C:\Users\Owner

Comment: Then surely that's the first thing to check, given that error message?